# How to use “na_values='?'” option in the pd.read.csv() function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find the operation with `na_values='?'` option in the `pd.read.csv()` function.

So that I can find the list of rows containing "?" value and then remove that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the rows which are contain "?" in pandas dataframe, you can try with:

suppose you have `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

`df`:

```
    A           B
0   Maths       4/13/2017
1   Physics     4/15/2016
2   English     4/16/2016
3   test?dsfsa  9/15/2016
```

check if column A contain "?" to generate new `df1`:

```
df1 = df[df.A.str.contains("\?")==False]
```

`df1` will be:

```
    A       B
0   Maths   4/13/2017
1   Physics 4/15/2016
2   English 4/16/2016
```

which will give you the new `df1` which doesn't contain "?".

Answer (score 3):

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

#test data
temp=u"""id,col1,col2,col3
1,13?,15,14
1,13,15,?
1,12,15,13
2,?,15,?
2,18,15,13
2,18?,15,13"""
#in real data use
#df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (df)
   id col1  col2 col3
0   1  13?    15   14
1   1   13    15    ?
2   1   12    15   13
3   2    ?    15    ?
4   2   18    15   13
5   2  18?    15   13
```

If want remove values with `?` which are separately or substrings need mask created by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and then check if at least one `True` per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('?', regex=False)))
      id   col1   col2   col3
0  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False   True  False   True
4  False  False  False  False
5  False   True  False  False

m = ~df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('?', regex=False)).any(axis=1)
print (m)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool

df = df[m]
print (df)
   id col1  col2 col3
2   1   12    15   13
4   2   18    15   13
```

If want replace only separately `?` simply compare value:

```
print (df.astype(str) == '?')
      id   col1   col2   col3
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False   True  False   True
4  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False

m = ~(df.astype(str) == '?').any(axis=1)
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool

df = df[m]
print (df)
   id col1  col2 col3
0   1  13?    15   14
2   1   12    15   13
4   2   18    15   13
5   2  18?    15   13
```

---

It replace all `?` to `NaN`s is necessary parameter `na_values` and [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) if want remove all rows with `NaN`s:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

#test data
temp=u"""id,col1,col2,col3
1,13?,15,14
1,13,15,?
1,12,15,13
2,?,15,?
2,18,15,13
2,18?,15,13"""
#in real data use
#df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values='?')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), na_values='?')
print (df)
   id col1  col2  col3
0   1  13?    15  14.0
1   1   13    15   NaN
2   1   12    15  13.0
3   2  NaN    15   NaN
4   2   18    15  13.0
5   2  18?    15  13.0


df = df.dropna()
print (df)
   id col1  col2  col3
0   1  13?    15  14.0
2   1   12    15  13.0
4   2   18    15  13.0
5   2  18?    15  13.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
na_values = ['NO CLUE', 'N/A', '0']
requests = pd.read_csv('some-data.csv', na_values=na_values)
```

Create a list with useless parameters and use it trough reading from file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please include a brief description of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"??" or "####" type of junk values can be converted into missing value, since in python all the blank values can be replaced with nan. Hence you can also replace these type of junk value to missing value by passing them as as list to the parameter
'na_values'.

```
data_csv = pd.read_csv('test.csv',na_values = ["??"])
```